# How to toggle flip Imageview horizontally in android

Tags: android, imageview, flip

I have an Imageview and I want to flip picture horizontally whenever user click on the Button named "Flip Picture" . and when User click this button second time it should return to orignal state in other words flip back.

So it should repeat this behavior. I found this useful code to flip the image view with out using external library , but do not know how to flip back:

Here is the Code :

```
 public Bitmap flipImage(Bitmap src, int type) {
    // create new matrix for transformation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // if vertical
    if(type == FLIP_VERTICAL) {
        // y = y * -1
        matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
    }
    // if horizonal
    else if(type == FLIP_HORIZONTAL) {
        // x = x * -1


        // unknown type
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    // return transformed image
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

and here is how I am trying to apply it on my Image view named FlipImage

```
Flipimage.setImageBitmap(flipImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.doom01),2));
```

Comment: maybe lib? [FlipImageView](https://github.com/castorflex/FlipImageView). may be ported to lower APIs with [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)

Comment: Flipping back is the same thing. newScale = -1 * currentScale.

Answer (score 0):

I found Answer My self while testing and trying :
Just flip the values it will flip the image view back : Here is the magic in this line :

**On first click :**

```
matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
```

**On Second Click :**

```
matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
```

So you can initialize the counter and also can use Toggle button of android.